# CKEDITOR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getComputedStyle')

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

```
ckeditor.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getComputedStyle')
at CKEDITOR.tools.extend.getComputedStyle (ckeditor.js:105:296)
at $.getDirection (ckeditor.js:128:386)
at $.setup (ckeditor.js:378:171)
at $.m (ckeditor.js:889:341)
at ckeditor.js:28:472
```

I am getting the above error when issuing the following

```
$('.htmleditor').each(function(e){
                CKEDITOR.replace(this.id,{
                removePlugins       :'scayt,contextmenu,liststyle,tabletools,uploadimage,image2,insertpre',
                extraPlugins                :'autogrow',
                autoGrow_minHeight          :300,
                autoGrow_maxHeight          :1000,
                disableNativeSpellChecker       :false,
                toolbar                 :[{ name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','-','RemoveFormat','Link','Unlink'] }],
                height                          : '200px',
                width                               : '100%',
                enterMode                           : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR 
                });
            });
```

the weird thing is, that on some workstations it works fine, on other workstations it works some of the time and not others.  On workstations where there are issues, it seems to be fairly consistently bad on chromium-based browsers, but works on firefox all the time.

I normally issue the CKEDITOR.replace on $(document).ready.  **If I delay the CKEDITOR.replace by a second or 2, it works where it didn't work before.**

my environment is very complex with many includes and other javascript libraries being loaded.  If I reduce it down to just ckeditor in a simple page, it works fine.

so I know it's not necessarily a ckeditor issue, but if the information I've provided makes sense to any of you, perhaps you can suggest where in the mess of other stuff I should be looking to resolve the issue?  Or if there's a way of checking that CKE is happy before issuing the CKEDITOR.replace?  I've tried try/catch blocks, but they don't work.

thanks in advance

Comment: PS we have been using CKeditor for years and this has only started to be an issue in the last few months

Comment: Did you ever figure out a particular cause for this issue?